# Python telebot cant restrict chat member

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to restrict chat member in writing but give him opportunity to invite users. I tried

`bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id, user_id, can_invite_users=True)`

But this restrict chat member of everything, he cant invite users.
Also I tried this

`bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)`
`bot.promote_chat_member(chat.get_chat_id(), us.get_user_id(), can_invite_users=True)`

But it also doesnt work
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
chat_id = message.chat.id
user_id = message.from_user.id
permissions = ChatMember(can_send_messages = False)
restrict_chat_member(chat_id, user_id, permissions)
```

This should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).